# PHP: trying to create a new line with "\n"

Tags: php, newline

i'm writing this:

```
echo "foo";
echo "\n";
echo "bar";
```

and "bar" is not written in the line below.

What am i doing wrong?

Javi

Comment: using browser to check output?

Comment: Did you View source if you are using a browser? That is where the newline would show, in just the source code. Also, what OS are you using? Some require an \r\n.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Newlines in HTML are expressed through `<br>`, not through `\n`.

Using `\n` in PHP creates a newline in the source code, and HTML source code layout is unconnected to HTML screen layout.

Comment: Does that means that $message = "my name \n is TheBump";
echo $message;

my name
is TheBump

??

Answer (score 20):

If you want a new line character to be inserted into a plain text stream then you could use the OS independent global PHP_EOL

```
echo "foo";
echo PHP_EOL ;
echo "bar";
```

In HTML terms you would see a newline between foo and bar if you looked at the source code of the page.

ergo, it is useful if you are outputting say, a loop of values for a select box and you value having html source code which is "prettier" or easier to read for yourself later. e.g.

```
foreach( $dogs as $dog )
echo "<option>$dog</option>" . PHP_EOL ;
```

Comment: I'd say  `echo "<option>$dog</option>\n";` is way readable than yours

Comment: But it wouldn't be OS independent so would be less portable, and I was claiming that the generated HTML source code would be more readable - but actually I find lines containing PHP_EOL easier to scan because I can tell where its headed.

Comment: I tried this but I needed to use \t to make the HTML line up anyway.

Comment: this is the only way i found to make html source page readable (including javascript generated by php code, in my case array definitions), i.e: debugging javascript code.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to write plain text, you must ensure the content type is set to `Content-Type: text/plain`. Example:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

If you are dealing with HTML, you have two options. One is to inset a new line using `<br>` (Or `<br />` for XHTML). The other is to put the plain text in a `<pre>` element (In this case "pre" stands for preformatted).

Comment: Please explain the downvote? It would be good to know what was wrong with my answer so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 7):

PHP generates HTML. You may want:

```
echo "foo";
echo "<br />\n";
echo "bar";
```

Comment: there is no need for the \n there

Comment: PHP does not *generate* HTML.

Comment: Looks like @Hendrik you have never had to debug *generated* HTML source code

Comment: @Felix care to share your brilliant knowledge of proper terminology?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Sure. PHP just outputs text (characters), nothing more nothing less. It depends what you do with the output. E.g. the OPs code would create the desired result when run from the commandline. Saying that *PHP generates HTML* is just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

if your text has newlines, use nl2br php function:

```
<?php
$string = "foo"."\n"."bar";
echo nl2br($string);
?>
```

This should look good in browser

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're viewing the output in a web browser you have at least two options:

1. Surround your text block with `<pre>` statements
2. Change your `\n` to an HTML `<br>` tag (`<br/>` will also do)

Answer (score 2):

Since it wasn't mentioned, you can also use the CSS white-space property

```
body{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Which tells the browser to preserve whitespace so that

```
<body>
    <?php
        echo "hello\nthere";
    ?>
</body>
```

Would display

```
hello
there
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use \n as a new line in php.

### **Code Snippet :**

```
 <?php
  echo"Fo\n";
  echo"Pro";
?>
```

*Output:*

> Fo
>   Pro

Answer (score 1):

It will be written on a new line if you examine the source code of the page. If you want it to appear on a new line when it is rendered in the browser, you'll have use a `<br />` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me...

```
echo nl2br("\n");
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer was so obvious and it took me forever to figure out:

```
echo "foo
bar";
```

I know that looks like it's wrapping. It's not. What I did is I literally hit <kbd>return</kbd> halfway through the string, between `foo` and `bar`. It creates a new line in the HTML source and makes your PHP look horrible. This was in Linux/Apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "foo<br />bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

We can apply `\n` in php by using two type

1. Using CSS

   ```
   body {
       white-space: pre-wrap;
   }
   ```

   Which tells the browser to preserve whitespace so that

   ```
   <body>
       <?php
           echo "Fo\n Pro";
       ?>
   </body>
   ```

   Result:

   > Fo
   >   Pro
2. Using `nl2br`

   **`nl2br`**: Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

   ```
   <?php
       echo nl2br("Fo.\nPro.");
   ?>
   ```

   Result

   > Fo. 
   >   Pro.

Answer (score 0):

the html element break line depend of it's `white-space` style property.
in the most of the elements the default `white-space` is `auto`, which mean break line when the text come to the width of the element.
if you want the text break by `\n` you have to give to the parent element the style:
`white space: pre-line`, which will read the `\n` and break the line, or
`white-space: pre` which will also read `\t` etc.
note: to write `\n` as break-line and not as a string , you have to use a double quoted string (`"\n"`)
if you not wanna use a white space, you always welcome to use the **HTML Element for break line**, which is `<br/>`

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = 'John' ; <br/>
$b = 'Doe' ; <br/>
$c = $a.$b"&lt;br/>";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.