# Trying to echo to a new line and isn't working

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: trying to create a new line with “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674703/php-trying-to-create-a-new-line-with-n)
>   [line break help in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879617/line-break-help-in-php)

Hello I have been trying to echo to a new line in PHP using the \n thing and it just isn't working, I have tried separating it just in case PHP got confused or something and it still isn't working, HELP!!

This is my code, you shouldn't need to know it all:

Take "id" to be 1, "sender" to be "test" and "message" to be "test"

```
echo($rows."\n");

while($rowarray = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo($rowarray["id"].") From: ".$rowarray["sender"]." - ".$rowarray["message"]."\n");

}
```

I want it to print out like this:

```
1 (or how many rows there are)
1) From: test - test
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate help

Comment: Are you viewing output in the browser?

Comment: in html a new line <br>, browser read\interprit html not plain text

Comment: Are you trying to echo out a `\n` in a HTML document? If you are, you'll need to use `<br>` instead.

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674703/php-trying-to-create-a-new-line-with-n?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you're viewing this output in the browser, try adding a break tag instead of a newline.

```
echo($rows."<br />");

while($rowarray = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo($rowarray["id"].") From: ".$rowarray["sender"]." - ".$rowarray["message"]."<br />");
}
```

I'll also add that the mysql* extension is being deprecated, you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @mike No idea. He had them, so I left them.

Comment: Well, I am getting it using a Lua script. So I dont know how it will read it? Should I use <br /> in that case?

Comment: @user1819037 It depends entirely on where you are viewing the output. If you are viewing the output in a browser, you need to use break tags as I specified.

Comment: I am using a lua script in a game and it obtains all the HTML tags. And I am reading it line by line.